# Excel Regression: What to do if one of my P values aren't acceptable but can't be removed?

Tags: regression, p-value, excel

I am doing regression in excel and I have dummy variables for Quarter (seasonal values) P values for Q2 and Q3 are significant but my Q1 P value seems too high. I can't exactly pull out Q1 ... What should I do?

Here is my output.

```
Intercept Pvalue  1.3208E-08
PRD1      Pvalue  .00002834
Q1        Pvalue  .6863222747 <-- this one concerns me
Q2        Pvalue  6.22284E-06
Q3        Pvalue  1.22817E-07
PRD2      Pvalue  0.115615524
```

Comment: This may be obvious to someone with more knowledge but if my user of this output views a forecast for Q1 wouldn't it be useless, or wrong at best? It's okay to leave in coefficient's based on items with high P values? Please help me to understand. I am struggling with how to handle these types of issues.

Comment: Wondering if including an item with a high P value destroys the whole regression model? Usually I just run the regression again without an item pulling a high P value but in this case it's Q1 and I can't exactly have Q2 3 and 4 without Q1..~confused

Comment: thank you user777 that helps! I am glad to know it's not compromising my overall model

Comment: This isn't off-topic, but might be a duplicate of ??? something?

Comment: ok, well then can you link me to the duplicate thread so I can read the answer?

Comment: It must be there, but somebody else will have to do the search because now it is to late at night here. But the issue is that the dummys for different Quarters really constitute together one variable (in this case with four possible values, so you need three dummys to represent it. Those three dummys **together constitute on variable** (In R such variables are calleds "factors". You shouldnt look at at the individual t-values for each coefficient, but construct one F-test for the complete variable (which will have three degrees of freedom).

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's one total variable with the question being is this item seasonal or not. Which is why I was shocked to find out the the answer is YES and NO. user777 explained this by pointing out that it means Q1 isn't statistically different than Q4 (my implied factor). That makes perfect sense but now the question becomes, should I allow the Q1 coefficient to impact the forecast or not...?? I could omit it but then as you said, I would have to omit all quarters. Which is why I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: Factors, like quarters here, should always be treated as a totality. Leave IT in with all its dummys, orleave IT out, completely. That one of the individual coefficients is nonsignificant is a nonissue

Comment: when would I omit completely? If all factors are non significant?

Comment: You must construct one Ftest for the factor! How tp do that in Excel I dont know

Comment: Maybe I will just assume if my adjusted R^2 is improved with it in and my overall significance of F is better then I can leave it in. Else omit

Comment: I want to second Richards comment here. To answer your question faithfully, we need to know what you intend to use the model for.  For example, do you want to learn whether the different quarters have different associations with your response? Or, would you like to make predictions?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your main question:
If we interpret this output to mean that the effect of the Q1 dummy is not significantly different from 0, all that means is that the effect in Q1 is basically the same as in Q4, which is your reference category. So there's only strong evidence of the dummy value being important for Q2 and Q3.

In a comment, you write

> Wondering if including an item with a high P value destroys the whole regression model? Usually I just run the regression again without an item pulling a high P value but in this case it's Q1 and I can't exactly have Q2 3 and 4 without Q1..~confused

This isn't great. If you're interested in whether some, if any, predictors are useful in predicting some outcome, a good place to start is with tools like lasso or elastic net regression. These methods fit a penalized model to your data that filters out poor predictors without incurring multiple comparisons problems. These topics are discussed at length elsewhere on this site.

Comment: "this isn't great" meaning Q1 in my model isn't great? The only tool we have available is Excel with the VBA toolpak regression analysis plugin. With that being said the coefficient for Q1 isn't 0 so if I allow my users to select Q1 it will forecast something different than if my users forecast for Q4. So I was concerned with allowing this since I know P value is so high for Q1.

Comment: "Different" doesn't mean wrong.

Comment: but the change that is making it "different" is being driven by an input with crazy high P-value. Seems like I shouldn't allow it to affect the forecast. That's essentially my whole question. Based on your input I gather that I shouldn't worry about it but I am not entirely sure I understand why not.

Comment: You should try to understand, but at least, dont worry! Your worrying without understanding might only make matters worse.

Comment: Life wisdom FTW

Comment: @JohnsonJason, The suggestion to use LASSO or elastic net is fine *in case the goal is prediction*. However, note than *explanatory* modelling and *predictive* modelling are solving different problems; a nice overview is given in Shmueli ["To Explain or To Predict"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1101.0891.pdf) (2010). Since the OP does not make it explicit, I though I should note this.